# ApplePay doesn't work on devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

I have two problems, 1) first of all when I've started application and tap on ApplePay button I have an exception without additional information, what did I do wrong?
2) Second, in a delegate method

```
paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
               didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                        completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion
```

for some reason payment.token.paymentData == nil and I don't understand why. What I did: activate ApplePay in a target, added certificate in Apple Developer Account, and create object like this:

```
- (PKPaymentRequest *)paymentRequest
{
    PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [[PKPaymentRequest alloc] init];
    paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = @"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = @[PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard];
    paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability3DS;
    paymentRequest.countryCode = @"RU";
    paymentRequest.currencyCode = @"RUB";
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems =
    @[
      [PKPaymentSummaryItem summaryItemWithLabel:@"Ticket" amount:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2000"]]
      ];

    return paymentRequest;
}
```

Comment: May this will give some help:[http://stackoverflow.com/a/33786066/5575752](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33786066/5575752)

Comment: canMakePayments and canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks return YES on simulator, and NO on devices

Comment: in simulator for testing purpose it will return YES, you need to check in real device, if it returns NO then there is problem somewhere in code or configuration.

Comment: Ok, is always on simulator paymentData kind of class NSZeroData?